While running schedule.yml file throws error Identifier 'github' has already been declared
While running the schedule-playwright.yml github actions workflow, getting following error SyntaxError: Identifier 'github' has already been declared
Could someone please advise how can I fix this issue ?
note: playwright.yml file is running successfully.
//schedule-playwright.yml
name: Scheduled 11:16 PM Playwright e2e Test run

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '16 13 * * *' # This is UTC time; 10:35 PM AEST is 12:35 PM UTC

jobs:
  trigger_playwright:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Trigger Playwright e2e Tests workflow
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const { github } = require('@actions/github');

            async function run() {
              try {
                await github.getOctokit(process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN).actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
                  owner: github.context.repo.owner,
                  repo: github.context.repo.repo,
                  workflow_id: 'playwright.yml',
                  ref: 'main'
                });
                console.log('Workflow dispatched successfully');
              } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error dispatching workflow:', error);
              }
            }
            
            run();

//playwright.yml file
 name: Playwright e2e Tests
    on:
      push:
        branches: [ main, master ]
      pull_request:
        branches: [ main, master ]
    jobs:
      test:
        timeout-minutes: 60
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
          with:
            node-version: lts/*
        - name: Install dependencies
          run: npm ci
        - name: Install Playwright Browsers
          run: npx playwright install --with-deps
        - name: Run Playwright tests
          run: |
            npx playwright test 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r line; do
              echo "$line"
            done
        - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
          if: always()
          with:
            name: playwright-report
            path: playwright-report/
            retention-days: 30


I think you do not need const { github } = require('@actions/github');.

Thank you I will try with out that declaration part and will  reply soon

https://github.com/actions/github-script?tab=readme-ov-file#actionsgithub-script - "The following arguments will be provided: - github ..."

@user459872 I am getting below error now :
Error dispatching workflow: TypeError: github.getOctokit is not a function
at run (eval at callAsyncFunction (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:15143:16)

@soccerway You don't need github.getOctokit. github itself is a pre-authenicated client. You can call the API using github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch

Try this:
name: dispatch

on:
  workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  dispatch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      actions: write
    steps:
      - name: Trigger Playwright e2e Tests workflow
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const workflowName = "Playwright e2e Tests";

            const workflows = await github.rest.actions.listRepoWorkflows({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo
            });

            const workflow = workflows.data.workflows.find(wf => wf.name === workflowName);

            if (!workflow) {
              throw new Error(`Workflow with name '${workflowName}' not found`);
            }

            await github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              workflow_id: workflow.id,
              ref: 'main'
            });

Judging by the code, your intent is to simply trigger 'playwright.yml' workflow after the scheduled workflow. Another way to achieve this is to add
workflow_run trigger to you platwright.yml workflow:
name: Playwright e2e Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, master ]
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Scheduled 11:16 PM Playwright e2e Test run]
    types: [completed]


the above first option provided is giving some error,  should i add owner: and repo: ? like this
owner: context.repo.owner, repo: context.repo.repo,

Tried that one, I am getting below error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createWorkflowDispatch') Error: Unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createWorkflowDispatch')

It must be github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch

I have updated the answer to include a complete workflow that can be triggered manually. You have to choose "dispatch" workflow in the left-hand side bar and then click "Run workflow" button on the right. You can not use workflow file name when creating a dispatch event. You have to use internal workflow ID, that can be found by iterating over workflow repos.
